# Google Hangouts in my website as a chat/messaging system

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-hangouts

I currently have Google OAuth 2.0 for authentication. Next I want to be able to use google hangouts in my website so users can chat with each other, along with showing their contact list.  So basically I want it to look like how it is on gmail but on my website for hangouts. Main reason for doing this, I want my users to be able use hangouts as a mode of communication. Please let me know if this is possible and provide the necessary resources, an example/demo of this working would really be helpful.

Comment: Azzaaaaaaaaaaaaaakaboom then its done again. (((Slowly disappear into the shadow))).............................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can. More information about google hangouts API here https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started

Comment: Thank you for this information, do you know if there is a demo anywhere, so I can see if this is exactly what I need?

Comment: I was looking for more of one implemented into a website, these examples are taking me to a video chat.

Comment: They don't provide any API to do text chat - I don't think this would be easy if not impossible

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Im afraid there's no API at the moment available (nor plans for that) to access the text chat feature of Hangouts.